# Random password generation when admin creates employees in admin site

Tags: python, django

I have inherited three users from the User model, namely the Admin, Employee, and Relative.

**models.py**

```
config = RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')

class UserManager( BaseUserManager):
    
    def _create_user(self, PAN_ID, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not PAN_ID:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a PAN_ID')
        extra_fields['email'] = self.normalize_email(extra_fields["email"])
        user = self.model(PAN_ID=PAN_ID, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_user(self, PAN_ID, password=None, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(PAN_ID, password, **extra_fields)
    
    def create_superuser(self, PAN_ID, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(PAN_ID, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        
    PAN_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128, null=False, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField( max_length=60, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    holding = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "PAN_ID"
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'name', 'holding']
    

    
class Admin(User):
    pass    
    
    
class Employee(User):
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=89, null=True)
    
    
class Relative(User):
    reference = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creator")
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from base.models import Admin, Employee, Relative, User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from mass import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from abc import ABC
from django.utils import timezone
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
from  django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Relative)
def mail(sender,instance, *args, **kwargs ):
   subject = "Hi"
   message  = f"Your password is {instance.password} " 
   from_email = None
   recipient_list = [instance.email]
   send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None) 

class RandomPasswordAndEmailMixin:
    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not self.instance.pk:
            instance = super().save(commit=False)
            instance.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password())
            return instance.save()
        else:
            self.cleaned_data.pop("password")
            return super.save(commit)
                
class UserModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('is_staff', 'is_active', 'password')
        
        
class EmployeeModelForm(RandomPasswordAndEmailMixin, UserModelForm):
    class Meta(UserModelForm.Meta):
        model = Employee
          
@admin.register(Employee)        
class EmployeeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, RandomPasswordAndEmailMixin):
    form = EmployeeModelForm
```

The Admin will be the superuser. The Admin will go to the admin site and perform CRUD on Employees and Relatives. In the form, there I just want the Admin to enter an Employee/Relative's username(PAN_ID), password, and email. On clicking 'Save', the corresponding signal for the mail should be sent and email would be sent so the password should be accessible in the **mail** function.  The password should be generated automatically by make_password. I 'm getting the following error.

> Internal Server Error: /admin/base/employee/add/ Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 179, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py",
> line 614, in wrapper
> return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py",
> line 130, in _wrapped_view
> response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py",
> line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
> response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py",
> line 233, in inner
> return view(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py",
> line 1653, in add_view
> return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)   File
> "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py",
> line 43, in _wrapper
> return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py",
> line 130, in _wrapped_view
> response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py",
> line 1534, in changeform_view
> return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)   File
> "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py",
> line 1580, in _changeform_view
> self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)   File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\djangodev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py",
> line 1093, in save_model
> obj.save() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save' [22/Jan/2021 15:13:17] "POST /admin/base/employee/add/
> HTTP/1.1" 500 112227

Comment: I'd suggest using django-allauth to create your users and send them verification emails. The users then set their own passwords upon verification. Much more secure than emailing passwords; https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Comment: thanks for the library @markwalker_. I can use that.

Comment: In else case super().save(commit)

Comment: Thanks @greg . I corrected it but still it seems the error is in some line before. https://dpaste.com/87S9J3AWH. Please add it as a correction above. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by overwriting the ModelAdmin subclass' `save_model` method.
Docs:  [Django ModelAdmin save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model). To make it reusable I just put it as a mixin.

```
class RandomPasswordAndEmailMixin:
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not form.instance.pk:
            user = form.save(commit=False) 
            user.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password(20))
            user.save() 
            form.save_m2m()

        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

@admin.register(Employee)        
class EmployeeModelAdmin(RandomPasswordAndEmailMixin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('is_staff', 'password')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the else clause to `super().save(commit)`.